# Adding Two Tables into seperate columns via SQL 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Hi guys I'm struggling to pull data from TWO tables into separate columns within one query

Currently the code I have looks like this

```
Declare @Begin Varchar(60),
        @End Varchar(60)
Set @Begin = '2014-05-22  06:00:00' 
Set @End = '2014-06-01  06:00:00'

SELECT 
    ID='10T'
    ,DATEPART(month,A.[DateTime]) Month
    ,DATEPART(day,A.[DateTime]) Day
    ,DATEPART(hour,A.[DateTime]) Hour
    ,avg(A.[kw]) hourly_kWh
    ,avg(A.[KVAr]) hourly_kVarh
    ,avg(A.[KVAReal]) hourly_kVAh
    ,(case when(DATEPART(hour,A.[DateTime]) =6 and DATEPART(hour,A.[DateTime]) 18) then 'D' else 'N' end)  shift
  FROM [POWER].[dbo].[IT10t_PAC3200] AS A
  where DateTime = @Begin and DateTime  @End
  group by DATEPART(Hour,[DateTime]),DATEPART(Day,[DateTime]),DATEPART(Month,[DateTime])

union

SELECT 
    ID='4T'
    ,DATEPART(month,B.[DateTime]) Month
    ,DATEPART(day,B.[DateTime]) Day
    ,DATEPART(hour,B.[DateTime]) as Hour
    ,avg(B.[kw]) hourly_kWh
    ,avg(B.[KVAr]) hourly_kVarh
    ,avg(B.[KVAReal]) hourly_kVAh
    ,(case when(DATEPART(hour,B.[DateTime]) =6 and DATEPART(hour,B.[DateTime]) 18) then 'D' else 'N' end)  shift
  FROM [POWER].[dbo].[ITfurnace] AS B 
  where DateTime = @Begin and DateTime  @End
  group by DATEPART(Hour,[DateTime]),DATEPART(Day,[DateTime]),DATEPART(Month,[DateTime])

  order by ID,month,day,hour asc;
```

NOW this gives me this result

```
ID  Month   Day Hour    hourly_kWh  hourly_kVarh    hourly_kVAh shift
10T 5       22  6       269.278551  80.771587      294.038997       D
10T 5       22  7       241.213296  75.991689      268.085872       D
10T 5       22  8       283.925     93.302777      319.211111       D
4T  5       22  6       834.679665  238.245125     870.640668       D
4T  5       22  7       548.476454  164.764542     576.814404       D
4T  5       22  8       834.111111  237.055555     870.888888       D
```

I tried using a join function with no success ( I'm not understanding the logic behind it) can you please assist me in edit my query to separate the ID that are now in different rows be moved to  columns. Because the Month, day, hour is the same between the different Id's

The result should look something like this

```
Month   Day Hour    hourly_kWh_10T  hourly_kWh_4T   shift
5       22  6       269.278551      834.679665      D
```

Comment: You can do this by using either a `CASE expression` or by using `PIVOT`.

Answer (score 0):

Couple different ways you could do this: as mentioned, a `CASE` expression would work well, but since you're actually pulling data from different tables I would do something like the following using your `UNION` and adding in an outer `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` statement employing aggregates to clear out the `NULL` values.

```
Declare @Begin Varchar(60),
        @End Varchar(60)
Set @Begin = '2014-05-22  06:00:00' 
Set @End = '2014-06-01  06:00:00'


SELECT 
    [Month], 
    [Day], 
    [Hour], 
    MAX(hourly_kWh_10T), 
    MAX(hourly_kVarh_10T), 
    MAX(hourly_kVAh_10T),
    MAX(hourly_kWh_4T), 
    MAX(hourly_kVarh_4T), 
    MAX(hourly_kVAh_4T)
    [Shift]
FROM 
  (
    SELECT 
        ID='10T'
        ,DATEPART(month,A.[DateTime]) Month
        ,DATEPART(day,A.[DateTime]) Day
        ,DATEPART(hour,A.[DateTime]) Hour
        ,avg(A.[kw]) hourly_kWh_10T
        ,avg(A.[KVAr]) hourly_kVarh_10T
        ,avg(A.[KVAReal]) hourly_kVAh_10T
        ,NULL hourly_kWh_4T
        ,NULL hourly_kVarh_4T
        ,NULL hourly_kVah_4T
        ,(case when(DATEPART(hour,A.[DateTime]) =6 and DATEPART(hour,A.[DateTime]) 18) then 'D' else 'N' end)  shift
      FROM [POWER].[dbo].[IT10t_PAC3200] AS A
      where DateTime = @Begin and DateTime  @End
      group by DATEPART(Hour,[DateTime]),DATEPART(Day,[DateTime]),DATEPART(Month,[DateTime])

    union

    SELECT 
        ID='4T'
        ,DATEPART(month,B.[DateTime]) Month
        ,DATEPART(day,B.[DateTime]) Day
        ,DATEPART(hour,B.[DateTime]) as Hour
        ,NULL
        ,NULL
        ,NULL
        ,avg(B.[kw]) hourly_kWh_4T
        ,avg(B.[KVAr]) hourly_kVarh_4T
        ,avg(B.[KVAReal]) hourly_kVAh_4T
        ,(case when(DATEPART(hour,B.[DateTime]) =6 and DATEPART(hour,B.[DateTime]) 18) then 'D' else 'N' end)  shift
      FROM [POWER].[dbo].[ITfurnace] AS B 
      where DateTime = @Begin and DateTime  @End
      group by DATEPART(Hour,[DateTime]),DATEPART(Day,[DateTime]),DATEPART(Month,[DateTime])
  ) s
GROUP BY 
    [Month],
    [Day],
    [Hour],
    [Shift]
```

I would definitely avoid using the SQL Server reserved keywords (`Month`, `Shift`, etc.) that you see in the [brackets].  Without having your data to run against, I can't be completely certain but this query should give you the results you are hoping for.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Ahiggins, can you please explain to me why you added the extra outer select section specifically the Max(*)? Thanks

Comment: I converted your three columns in the UNION to six - three each for the two groups of data you are using.  That means that any given row will always have NULLs in three of the six fields (10T returns NULL in the 4T fields, and vise versa).  In order to roll up the data to a single row, the MAX() function will retrieve the value that is not null, effectively combining the separate rows of the UNION into a single row with the value you're looking for.  This only works because you know for sure that you'll have one actual value for any given output row.

Answer (score 0):

Taking the result of your original query as a starting point (as I don't have neither the DDL nor original data), you can PIVOT it like this (the #t here contains the aforementioned result):

```
select Month, Day, Hour, shift, [10T] as hourly_kWh_10T, [4T] as hourly_kWh_4T 
from (
    select ID, Month, Day, Hour, shift, hourly_kWh from #t
) as source
pivot (
    max(hourly_kWh)
    for id in ([10T], [4T])
) as pvt
```